# How to calculate color shadows codes?

Tags: html, css, colors, color-scheme, color-space

I would like to know / calculate color codes of N red shadows (N can be 5, 20, or 50, for example).

How could I do this ?

I noticed, for example, that the following gives some red shadows:

- R = 255, G = B = 0..255
- R = 0..255, G = B = 0

Is there any known method to calculate shadows ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *calculate shadows*, but any RGB colour code that's high in the Red value and low in the Green and Blue values will give you a red colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to generate the shades of a color in HSV color-space. You can choose a base color (hue) and variate the saturation or the value, and then generate the RGB values for the generated colors. There is a nice [wikipedia article about the HSL/HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), where you can find the formulas to convert colors from  RGB to HSV and back.